# One to Many MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-design, foreign-keys, foreign-key-relationship

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MySQL Relationships](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216865/mysql-relationships)

I am trying to create a one to many relationship in MySQL with foreign keys.

Two tables, `user` and `location`. Each `user` can have many `location`s, but each `location` can have only one `user`.

How do I configure this? I am using HeidiSQL if that helps, though I can input code as well.

Comment: user (`id`, `username`, `location`);
location (`id`, `locationname`, `user`);

if user exists in location, delete prior record.

Comment: As a matter of fact, let me ask this question so I understand it better. How does MySQL know that it is a one-many relationship vs a one-one or many-many? That might be where I'm getting confused, because I feel that I understand it (creating the relationships) just not how they work.

Comment: @James: It's all in how the tables and foreign keys (FKs) are created. A one-to-one should be created so that the tables share the same Primary key (PK) with one table referencing the other as a FK. A one-to-many is created so that the table on the many side has a different PK and a FK column that points to the PK on the table on the one side. A many-to-many is created, as we discussed in your earlier question, by introducing a third table and essentially creating two one-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 57, accepted):

MySQL does not know, nor does it need to know if a relationship is 1-1, or 1-many.
No SQL supports many-many relationships, all require a intermediate table which splits a many-many relationship into 2 separate 1-many.

The difference is in the logic that controls the relationships, which is in the code that you write.
A 1-1 relationship is maintained by having the tables share the same primary key (PK).
With the secondary table declaring that PK as a foreign key pointing to the other tables PK.

```
Table chinese_mother (
id integer primary key,
name....
   

Table chinese_child (
id integer primary key,
name ....
....,
foreign key (id) references chinese_mother.id
```

The direction of the relationship `1 -> many` vs `many <- 1` is determined by the location of the link field.

Usually every table has a unique `id` and the link field is called `tablename_id`.
The table that has the link field in it is the `many` side of the relationship, the other table is on the `1` side.

> Each user can have many locations, but each location can have only one user.

```
Table user
id: primary key
name......
.....

Table location
id: primary key
user_id foreign key references (user.id)
x
y
.......
```

By placing the link field in the `location` table, you force things so that a location can only have 1 user. However a user can have many locations.

Answer (score 16):

There is an example here that is almost exactly what you need [foreign keys in innodb](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

```
CREATE TABLE parent (
  id INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=INNODB;

CREATE TABLE child (
  id INT,
  parent_id INT,
  INDEX par_ind (parent_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (parent_id) REFERENCES parent(id) ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=INNODB;
```

In your example user is the same as parent (a user has many locations, a parent has many childs) and location is the same as child (a location has one user, a child has one parent)