# Best approach to select from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have many tables like A1, B1, C1..etc. all with the same  row structure

```
Moz -  Attr1 - attr2
```

And one table that contains the names of all tables like:

```
Id(pk) - tname - input
1          A1      X
2          B1      Y
3          C1      Z
```

I'm looking for the best approach to get all of the A1, B1, C1 values in one view.
If possible without using UNION

Comment: any specific reason why you would avoid using UNION ?

Comment: by my opinion UNION is mostly slow

Comment: The best approach is to put them all into one properly indexed table. The next best option is to combine them in a UNION. Your opinion doesn't really come into it.

Comment: So, if I understand well, you want to pick table names from the table with Id/tname/input fields, and dynamically get the union from the tables listed in `tname` ?

Comment: @Axxess If you have correct primary keys which will allow a one to many database relationship, you could use inner joins - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217742/one-to-many-mysql

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your tables have the same structure, then all the data really belongs to **one** table. Let's call it `XY` for the sake of giving it a name here.

The table name "A1, B1" ... etc should be just another field in the XY table:

```
Moz -  Attr1 - attr2 - context
-      -       -       A1
-      -       -       B1
```

This table indeed needs to be properly indexed.
Assuming the `Moz` field is a primary key for each table, you then need to have (Moz,Context) as primary key in order to avoid issues with duplicate `Moz` values.

Getting an union of all tables is then just as simple and fast as a `SELECT * from XY`.

If you need to select a few of the tables: `SELECT * from XY WHERE context IN ('A1', 'B1')`

Generally speaking, it is a very bad idea to use dynamically created tables in a SQL RDBMS, because it completely defeats the purpose of "Relational", and will cause performance to be abysimal.

You just actually found out the hard way, because technically, your A1, B1, C1 tables are unrelated, and yet you want them to become related via the use of a union, which you don't want to use because it is "slow".
By storing the name as a field, you create a relation between the "table list" table and XY, can now use reasonably fast joins, and no further "CREATE TABLE" are ever needed.

See [Database normalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) to have a better explanation of these concepts.