# Is storing user comments in text files valid?

Tags: php, mysql, database

I'm currently **building a forum in PHP** and it has a user account system, options, etc. I have a MySQL database set up for handling posts. The structure is along the lines of something like this:

```
id                                   [int(11), AI]    The ID of the post.
author                               [varchar(20)]    The author of the post.
date                                 [datetime]       The day the post was published.
```

A bit primitive, yes, but I do not wish to reveal too many details about my database structure and I hope you can understand that.

I originally had a **bigtext column for storing notes and comments**. It would've been filled up with a strings like so:

```
user1("comment", "1 Example 2015"), user2("comment 2", "2 Example 2015")
```

I would parse it in PHP and display the notes and comments accordingly, but something crossed my mind:

***What would happen if I ran out of space?***

I don't know how much activity a forum post can get, but in the case that it **does grow to that extent**, or people continuously **append to the post** time and time again, **what would happen to to the table row?**

So I thought up a solution of **using a text file, filling it with the comments and storing it in a folder** just for the post. Does this seem like a **valid way** of storing comments?

Comment: Neither of these is right. Create a comments table and normalize your data.

Comment: I agree with @Ed Cottrell. You must have a table for your users and a table for your comments

Comment: You gonna join on that de-normalized text file?

Comment: "... but I do not wish to reveal too many details about my database structure and I hope you can understand that." -- No, we can't understand. You're not doing anything amazing. In fact, you are re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: @MECU Last I recall, I never said that I was doing anything amazing, but for the sake of the security of my database, I'd rather not inform the public of Stack Overflow nor the Internet of my database structure.

Comment: @EdCottrell Now that I look at it and understand, I firmly believe you're right. A comments table is the way to go, so thank you everyone for your time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're asking if storing the data in text files would work, then yeah you could definitely make it work. This is software development, a million ways to skin a cat. Now, is it the recommended way? Depends on who you talk to, but I would personally say no.

You must remember that these text files will also have a file size, just because the comments are in files, that does not mean the used disk space will magically disappear. And since you will be using files to store them, a lot of the built in functionality you have with SQL for querying and manipulating the data will be lost. I would personally use a one to many approach where one post would have many comments. Take a look at this article for more detail:

[One to Many MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217742/one-to-many-mysql)

Best of luck.

Comment: That is a great answer. I never took into account the power that SQL truly has, so thank you for this!

Answer (score 0):

To create a basic forum you need at least three tables (not including the users table). You would need a categories, topics, and comments table. Topics should contain the category id, comments should contain a topic id. Keep everything relational and you can grow fairly large before you run into any performance issues. Dont forget to index!