# Storing array in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

I am trying to figure out how to best store an array into a MySQL field that can be manipulated from PHPMyAdmin.

We are inputting employees into a table in a MySQL database, using PHPMyAdmin, and one of their columns is state licensing. We will be evaluating the states they are licensed in to determine if they are eligible to receive a particular lead that is being assigned to them in our CRM through a POST. We will check to see if their state licensing matches the customer's state along with some other parameters to determine if we should execute the lead assignment to them (ie, quota thresholds, active session, is it their turn?, etc..)

So employee #1 is licensed in CA, CO, OR and NJ and employee #2 is licensed in CA, FL, TX, and VA. How is this best represented in the MySQL database? I don't think we want this serialized because someone will be manually inputting the state licenses into the DB. Should I just leave it comma-delimitted? Ultimately I will build out a small interface for adding and removing employees but PHPMyAdmin is easier for us to use for now since it's already built.

I'd like to extract the field from the database, put the state licenses into an array for analysis then make a decision from there.

Comment: Don't store it in a single column; use a relational table.

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216865/mysql-relationships) has the basics of what you're trying to do. hopefully its helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it sounds like I will need to have a user table and also a state licensing table with a user id linking the two then just make each possible state license a table and mark it with a 1 if they're licensed in that state or nothing if not? Then I can just query to find the userID then analyze the state licensing table for user eligibility to receive a lead. I think I'm getting the work around to not easily storing an array..

User Table:
userID | userName | userEmail
123    | nate     | nate@domain.com

State Licensing Table:
userID | AZ | CA | CO | NJ | OR | VA
123    | 0  | 1  | 0  | 1  | 1  | 0

Comment: I ended up just storing it as comma-delimited and exploding it on querying it.

Answer (score 0):

There is no good way to store an array into a single field.

You need to examine your relational data and make the appropriate changes to your schema. See example below for a reference to this approach.

If you must save the array into a single field then the serialize() and unserialize() functions will do the trick. But you cannot perform queries on the actual content.

As an alternative to the serialization function there is also  json_encode() and json_decode().

Consider the following array

```
$a = array(
    1 => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    ),
    2 => array(
        'a' => 1,
        'b' => 2,
        'c' => 3
    ),
);
```

To save it in the database you need to create a table like this

```
$c = mysql_connect($server, $username, $password);
mysql_select_db('test');
$r = mysql_query(
    'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
$r = mysql_query(
    'CREATE TABLE test (
      id INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      a INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      b INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      c INTEGER UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )');
```