# how to store multiple values in a single cell in mysql using command line

Tags: mysql

I have already searched a lot,but unable to give me solution.
I have only one database table having two columns : User Name and Email Id. 
 I don't want any mapping table.
I want to insert more than one email Id for a single user with a comma separator.

what should my query in MySQL ?? I am using command Line
 1) when 1st time entry with unique user and multiple email Id and
 2) when I found user is already exist and email Id field have multiple Ids but not the one I am searching for so concatenate it with existing values.
Can you please provide me queries for above two mentioned scenarios.

Thank you so much in advance...

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Relationships](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8216865/mysql-relationships)

Comment: This is not what I have asked @sander Backus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

quite easy

```
insert into tableName('userName','test1@gmail.com,test2@gmail.com,test3@gamil.com');
```